# Classification based on list of words R

Tags: r, text-classification, stringr

I have a data set with article titles and abstracts that I want to classify based on matching words.

"This is an example of text that I want to classify based on the words that are matched from a list. This would be about 2 - 3 sentences long. word4, word5, text, text, text"

```
Topic 1     Topic 2     Topic (X)
word1       word4       word(a)
word2       word5       word(b)
word3       word6       word(c)
```

Given that that text above matches words in Topic 2, I want to assign a new column with this label. Preferred if this could be done with "tidy-verse" packages.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could split your long sentence in to each word and see if those words are in Topic1, 2 etc, if they are return the topic name. Not knowing how your data frame I can't give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sentence as a string and the topics in a data frame you can do something like this

```
input<- c("This is an example of text that I want to classify based on the words that are matched from a list. This would be about 2 - 3 sentences long. word4, word5, text, text, text")
df <- data.frame(Topic1 = c("word1", "word2", "word3"),Topic2 = c("word4", "word5", "word6"))

## This splits on space and punctation (only , and .)
input<-unlist(strsplit(input, " |,|\\."))

newcol <- paste(names(df)[apply(df,2, function(x) sum(input %in% x) > 0)], collapse=", ")
```

Given I am unsure of the data frame you want to add this too I have made a vector newcol.

If you had a data frame of long sentences then you can use a similar approach.

```
inputdf<- data.frame(title=c("This is an example of text that I want to classify based on the words that are matched from a list. This would be about 2 - 3 sentences long. word4, word5, text, text, text", "word2", "word3, word4"))
input <- strsplit(as.character(inputdf$title), " |,|\\.")

inputdf$newcolmn <-unlist(lapply(input, function(x) paste(names(df)[apply(df,2, function(y) sum(x %in% y)>0)], collapse = ", ")))
```